# How to use Typescript in browser with Babel and Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, browser, babeljs

I'm trying to use Typescript in my browser by using this architecture : [Typescript in browser architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBL7k.png)

But the import / export doesn't work when I use this command :

> **tsc && babel build-ts -d lib && webpack --config webpack.config.js**
>
> ERROR in ./lib/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'index'
> in 'C:\Users\aurel\Desktop\Platformer\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./lib/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file'
> in 'C:\Users\aurel\Desktop\Platformer\lib'

index.html :

```
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

index.ts

```
export const index = "test";
import { file } from 'file';

console.log(file)
```

file.ts

```
export const file = "test";
import { index } from 'index';

console.log(index)
```

---

webpack.config.js

```
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
   entry: {
   js: glob.sync("./lib/**/*.js"),  
},
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
},
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
"target": "es6",
"module": "amd",
"outDir": "./build-ts",
```

Do you have an idea ? I can't figure out how do to it, thanks in advance !

Comment: what is in your /lib directory when this command fails? is there an index.js or file.js file?

Comment: The lib directory contains my babel files ( index.js  and file.js )

Comment: Dovakeidy, instead of thanking my be editing my answer you should approve or upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imports should be relative not absolute:

```
export const index = "test";
import { file } from './file';

console.log(file)
```

```
export const file = "test";
import { index } from './index';

console.log(index)
```

By default, an absolute import will be searched for in the node_modules directories.

Comment: Oh my ! Thanks, I dont know how I didnt see that !